# MySQL null dates are not filtered out by query

Tags: mysql, date, null

In a table, there are several `date` columns. some of them contain `null`, the others are set with valid dates.

This query returns 17 records (and it is correct):

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

This query returns 6 records (and it is correct):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE selected_column IS NULL
```

This query returns 17 records (and it is wrong, obviously):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE selected_column IS NOT NULL
```

Any explanations?

***edit***
The create table statment:

```
CREATE TABLE `contracts` (  
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
`start_date` date NOT NULL,  
`end_date` date NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12323 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What data type is `selected_column`? Please show us the `create table` statement. Can you post a self-contained test case on http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Can you post the data in your database, or the queries at least

Comment: I wrote, it is a`date` data-type. the create table is now in the question

Comment: @yossi all columns won't take `NULL` values. Which one should have a row with a `NULL` value in one of the columns?

Comment: @VMai it seems so, i used sql to set it to null and missed the `0 rows affected`. after changing the field to accept null - it works.

Answer (score 0):

Column with NULL value is not listed in where clause. It seems to be the only explanation.

Try `Select selected_column from table where selected_column is not NULL`